# Tire gem: undefined method `detect'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I am using a few persisted Tire models in my Rails app. Searching has been working fine, using `Tire.search ['index1','index2'], :load => true do ...` But I now made a new index and model, and I get the following error when trying to include it in the search and access its results:

```
undefined method `detect' for #<AuthoredHistory:0x000001013d6a88>
```

I see it's coming from Tire::Results::Collection#results, down at the last line:

```
@response['hits']['hits'].map { |item| records[item['_type']].detect { |record| record.id.to_s == item['_id'].to_s } }
```

For some reason `records[item['_type']]` returns a Tire::Results::Collection object for my other models, but with the new class it returns an AuthoredHistory object, which is my actual model class. I saw something about this on the gem's github page, but I am not doing anything with Tire.configuration.wrapper. I am including Persistence, Search, and Callbacks modules in all indexed models.

Am I missing something? Can someone please point me in the right direction? (karmi, I'm hoping you can save me here!)

[UPDATE]

Now I'm getting somewhere... an error was occurring when only 1 result from a particular index is returned with the results. If there are 2 or more results from an index, it wraps it in Tire::Results::Collection. Now to find a hack...

[UPDATE again]

Hacky solution found! Look below for the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack that I believe works... not a pretty one, but that's the nature of the hack. If there is only ONE result for a particular model, the records do not return a `Tire::Results::Collection` object but rather just an object of the actual model, which fails on `detect`. So, I must check if we have a Collection or not, and if not, simply wrap it in an array. It seems to work for now, hopefully there are no ill effects down the road...

Here is the hack... this replaces the problematic line that I posted in the question:

```
@response['hits']['hits'].map do |item|
  collection = records[item['_type']].is_a?(Tire::Results::Collection) ?
    records[item['_type']] :
    [records[item['_type']]]
  collection.detect { |record| record.id.to_s == item['_id'].to_s }
end
```

ALSO! I had done a hack before to account for when the search results as a whole only returned one item. I had to insert this line right before the same problematic line above:

```
return [records[@response['hits']['hits'].first['_type']]] if @response['hits']['hits'].size == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the curly brace for the map before the detect. It should be this:

```
@response['hits']['hits'].map { |item| records[item['_type']] }.detect { |record| record.id.to_s == item['_id'].to_s }
```

I don't know the codebase well enough to know this for sure, but I think `records[item['_type']]` is going to be returning one of those `AuthoredHistory` objects, which don't have the `detect` method on them.

The `detect` method is used in `Enumerable` collections in Ruby, and that's kind of object that `map` returns (it'll return an `Array`) object. Therefore, the curly brace was in the wrong position.

Comment: That is certainly sound logic.. but using this causes more errors. Not sure if this is the solution as the line in question is included in the gem...?

Answer (score 0):

This should be now fixed in commit [`44eda24`](https://github.com/karmi/tire/commit/44eda24). See also issue [#725](https://github.com/karmi/tire/pull/725).